# Xcode 6 : linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation) again

Tags: ios

ld: 142 duplicate symbols for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

ld: 142 duplicate symbols for architecture i386

clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to solve the same problem with the following code.

Add this to the Library Search Paths in Build Settings and make sure you select recursive, delete other library paths which might be absolute paths.

```
$(PROJECT_DIR)
```

May be it will help you.

OR

You have duplicate symbol method which means there are duplicate file in project

In your Target's Build Phase, under "Compile Sources" check if there are duplicate file and delete one if you have duplication.

Hope this will help you.

Comment: still i don't solve the problem..plz share something different

Comment: Have you find the solution?

Comment: STILL NO.. can you help me?

Comment: @Thumarkishan  which file you are getting in duplicate symbol??

Comment: Fbsdkcorekit and fbsdkloginkit   @ bHuMiCA

Comment: Okay do one thing First of all delete this two framework from your project Do.move to trash. After that Add this file into your project.amd give $(PROJECT_DIR) into  Library Search Paths. And go to build phase and check  in Compile Sources that  it should be only one not twice.

Comment: @Thumarkishan If my answer is helpful to you please mark it as answer or give me upvotes